# Can't get leaving Activity to display over the entering Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I want my `LoginActivity` to slide upwards and reveal my `MainActivity` beneath it, just like how you would slide a card from the top of the deck. The exiting `Activity` should exit sliding upwards and the entering one should already be and stay in place. This would be achieved the way described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630576/change-the-z-order-of-activity-animations-on-android).

With the default behavior it was easy to do before **API level 24** because the leaving activity took a higher **Z-order** than the entering one. For whatever reason this was changed to the exact opposite in Android 7.0.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574898/z-order-changed-in-activity-transition-animations-on-android-7-0-nougat/39575426) suggests using `android:zAdjustment="bottom"` on the entering and `...="top"` on the exiting `Activity` to order them in the wanted way. However, this seems to be not working on neither **API 28 and 29** emulators. When using the above solution I see no transition animation because the entering `Activity` takes over and fully covers the animation of the exiting one. This does not change after several Clean/Rebuilds as suggested by the above answer.

Is it possible that this solution was broken somewhere after the change was done, or am I doing something wrong here? Is it even possible to implement this style of animation on current API levels?

`activity_out_top.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:zAdjustment="top"/>
</set>
```

`no_animation.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom"/>
</set>
```

I even tried starting the transition in two different ways:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle animate = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.activity_out_up).toBundle();
startActivity(intent, animate);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.activity_out_up);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was in the wrong the whole time. The solution was simple: the `zAdjustment` attribute must be on the `set` tag, not the `translate` tag. So simple yet easy to miss. My exit animation is the following now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```